# Sum of multiple input fields with same name but not same id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am trying to make an jQuery function to make sum of some input fields with array name, but not same id.

```
<input name="ingredient[1]" type="text" id="autofield_1" class="ingrediente">

<input name="ingredient[2]" type="text" id="autofield_2" class="ingrediente">

<input name="ingredient[3]" type="text" id="autofield_3" class="ingrediente">

<input name="ingredient[4]" type="text" id="autofield_4" class="ingrediente">

<input name="ingredient[5]" type="text" id="autofield_5" class="ingrediente">

<input name="ingredient[6]" type="text" id="autofield_6" class="ingrediente">
```

Note: I use a button with jQuery function to add new field on press, is using `appendTo` to add more fields. sometimes I have more or less fields, the jQuery function must be dynamic, to apply on the number of input fields set.

Comment: What values would you expect the user to enter? What result would you want to get from those `input`s?

Comment: Access them by class `$( '.ingrediente' )` or name starts condition.

Comment: with sum you mean "numeric sum" or "concatenate strings"?

Comment: @BeNdErR numeric sum from input value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var sum = 0;
// or $( 'input[name^="ingredient"]' )
$( '.ingrediente' ).each( function( i , e ) {
    var v = parseInt( $( e ).val() );
    if ( !isNaN( v ) )
        sum += v;
} );
```